# Can't update first's array item

Tags: json, sql-update, postgresql-9.5

column type = jsonb

```
{
  "article": "1215",
  "availability": [
    {
      "currency": "usd",
      "discount": {
        "due_date": null,
        "is_active": false,
        "old_price": 3599
      },
      "is_available": true,
      "qty": 0,
```

I need to update **is_available = false,** (in the first array's item) because **qty = 0**.

I try this:

```
UPDATE product_imp
SET data = jsonb_set(data, '{availability, 0, is_available}', 'false', false)
where product_imp.data ->> '{availability, 0, qty}'::numeric = 0
```

But I get error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "{availability, 0, qty}"
LINE 3: where product_imp.data ->> '{availability, 0, qty}'::numeric...
                                   ^
SQL state: 22P02
Character: 125
```

Comment: Please add language used to tags of question (by edit(ing)).
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors in your code: the cast operator `::` binds strong than the `->>` operator, so Postgres tries to  convert `'{availability, 0, qty}'` to a numeric value.

The second error is, that you can't use `->>` to get a value based on a path, you need to use `#>>`

```sql
UPDATE product_imp
  SET data = jsonb_set(data, '{availability, 0, is_available}', 'false', false)
where (product_imp.data #>> '{availability, 0, qty}')::numeric = 0
```

Comment: I use this: "where 
(product_imp.data -> 'availability'->0->>'qty')::int = 0" . And it's work fine